# Pass user input value to random text string

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am trying to create a topic generator. I want to pass a user input value into a sentence. For example, I want a user to give me a keyword like Dog, then I want that user input to be passed as a variable to a random string of text. *eg: Top 5 Ways to Clean A Dog*

Here is what I currently have:

```
var randomStrings = [
    "Top 5 Ways To insert user input here ",
    "hello 2",
    "hello 3",
    "hello 4",
    "hello 5",
    "hello A",
    "hello B",
    "hello C",
    "hello D",
    "hello E"  // Note: No comma after last entry
];
function RndMsg() {
  var msg = randomStrings[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomStrings.length)];
  document.getElementById('randomDiv').innerHTML = msg;
}
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
 <h2>Select a keyword to optimize for</h2>
  <input placeholder="Keyword" type="text" id="keyword" name="user-input" required="">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="Generate" name="sessionid" onclick="RndMsg()"/>
</form>

<div >
 <p id="randomDiv"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the updated code below,

```js
var randomStrings = [
    "Top 5 Ways To insert user input here ",
    "hello 2",
    "hello 3",
    "hello 4",
    "hello 5",
    "hello A",
    "hello B",
    "hello C",
    "hello D",
    "hello E"  // Note: No comma after last entry
];
function RndMsg() {
  var msg = randomStrings[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomStrings.length)];
  
  var newMsg= '';
  $.each(randomStrings, function(i, str){
    
    if (str === msg){
      newMsg = str + ' ' + $('#keyword').val();
      randomStrings[i] = newMsg;
      return false;
      }
    
    });
    
  document.getElementById('randomDiv').innerHTML = newMsg;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
 <h2>Select a keyword to optimize for</h2>
  <input placeholder="Keyword" type="text" id="keyword" name="user-input" required="">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="Generate" name="sessionid" onclick="RndMsg()"/>
</form>

<div >
 <p id="randomDiv"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks it partially works. For some reason it is adding the keyword multiple times on a few of the random strings. I will make a fiddle in a moment

Comment: sure, are you expecting the keyword not to be duplicated in random string?

Comment: I would like to have the keyword output only used once per random string if possible. I am starting to understand how to go about it with your code but it is much more complex then what I was reading about on W3C

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do;

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
 <h2>Select a keyword to optimize for</h2>
  <input placeholder="Keyword" type="text" id="keyword" name="user-input" required="">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="Generate" name="sessionid" id="generate"/>
</form>

<div >
 <p id="randomDiv"></p>
</div>
```

and:

```
var randomStrings = [ //random string to attach to
    "Top 5 Ways To",
    "hello 2",
    "hello 3",
    "hello 4",
    "hello 5",
    "hello A",
    "hello B",
    "hello C",
    "hello D",
    "hello E"  // Note: No comma after last entry
];

var generate = document.getElementById('generate'); // grab the button from the html
//when the button is clicked do this function
generate.onclick= function () { 
//since the keyword can change, get it every time the user clicks generate and he gets a new topic
  var keyword = document.getElementById('keyword').value;
  var msg = randomStrings[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomStrings.length)];
//when inserting data written by the user into the page DO NOT USE INNERHTML! they can insert code here! use text content instead.
  document.getElementById('randomDiv').textContent = msg + " " + keyword;
}
```

Hope this helps!